# Ebay API - grabbing user products & grabbing individual product details

Tags: php, ebay-api

I have searched but there isn't too much documentaiton on using the ebay API and php output unless you are get profound in that area.

I have managed to find an example to output a certain users products but it isn't perfect.

I would also like to know how to output specific elements of an individual product like title, description, price....

below is what I have to get the products so any improvement would be great and and any direction to show an individual product would also be great

many thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<?php

require_once('DisplayUtils.php');  // functions to aid with display of information

//error_reporting(E_ALL);  // turn on all errors, warnings and notices for easier debugging
$sellerID='SellerIdHere';
$pageResults='';
if(isset($_POST['SellerID']))
{
  $s_endpoint = 'http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping';  // Shopping
  $f_endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';  // Finding
  $responseEncoding = 'XML';   // Format of the response
  $s_version = '667';   // Shopping API version number
  $f_version = '1.4.0';   // Finding API version number
  $appID   = 'AppIdHere'; //replace this with your AppID

  $debug   = true;
  $debug = (boolean) $_POST['Debug'];

  $sellerID  = urlencode (utf8_encode($_POST['SellerID']));   // cleanse input
  $globalID    = urlencode (utf8_encode($_POST['GlobalID']));

  $sitearray = array(
    'EBAY-US' => '0',
    'EBAY-ENCA' => '2',
    'EBAY-GB' => '3',
    'EBAY-AU' => '15',
    'EBAY-DE' => '77',
  );


  $siteID = $sitearray[$globalID];

  $pageResults = '';
  $pageResults .= getUserProfileResultsAsHTML($sellerID);
  $pageResults .= getFindItemsAdvancedResultsAsHTML($sellerID);

} // if


function getUserProfileResultsAsHTML($sellerID) {
  global $siteID, $s_endpoint, $responseEncoding, $s_version, $appID, $debug;
  $results = '';

  $apicall = "$s_endpoint?callname=GetUserProfile"
       . "&version=$s_version"
       . "&siteid=$siteID"
       . "&appid=$appID"
       . "&UserID=lordbrowns"

       . "&IncludeSelector=Details,FeedbackHistory"   // need Details to get MyWorld info
       . "&responseencoding=$responseEncoding";

  if ($debug) { print "<br />GetUserProfile call = <blockquote>$apicall </blockquote>"; }

  // Load the call and capture the document returned by the Shopping API
  $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

  if ($resp) {
    if (!empty($resp->User->MyWorldLargeImage)) {
      $myWorldImgURL = $resp->User->MyWorldLargeImage;
    } else {
      $myWorldImgURL = 'http://pics.ebaystatic.com/aw/pics/community/myWorld/imgBuddyBig1.gif';
    }
    $results .= "<table><tr>";
    $results .= "<td><a href=\"" . $resp->User->MyWorldURL . "\"><img src=\""
          . $myWorldImgURL . "\"></a></td>";
    $results .= "<td>Seller <br /> ";
    $results .= "Feedback score : " . $resp->User->FeedbackScore . "<br />";
    $posCount = $resp->FeedbackHistory->UniquePositiveFeedbackCount;
    $negCount = $resp->FeedbackHistory->UniqueNegativeFeedbackCount;
    $posFeedBackPct = sprintf("%01.1f", (100 * ($posCount / ($posCount + $negCount))));
    $results .= "Positive feedback : $posFeedBackPct%<br />";
    $regDate = substr($resp->User->RegistrationDate, 0, 10);
    $results .= "Registration date : $regDate<br />";

    $results .= "</tr></table>";

  } else {
    $results = "<h3>No user profile for seller $sellerID";
  }
  return $results;
} // function



function getFindItemsAdvancedResultsAsHTML($sellerID) {
  global $globalID, $f_endpoint, $responseEncoding, $f_version, $appID, $debug;

  $maxEntries = 3;

  $itemType  = urlencode (utf8_encode($_POST['ItemType']));
  $itemSort  = urlencode (utf8_encode($_POST['ItemSort']));

  $results = '';   // local to this function
  // Construct the FindItems call
  $apicall = "$f_endpoint?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced"
       . "&version=$f_version"
       . "&GLOBAL-ID=$globalID"
       . "&SECURITY-APPNAME=$appID"   // replace this with your AppID
       . "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=$responseEncoding"
       . "&itemFilter(0).name=Seller"
       . "&itemFilter(0).value=SellerIdHEre"
       . "&itemFilter(1).name=ListingType"
       . "&itemFilter(1).value=$itemType"
       . "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=$maxEntries"
       . "&sortOrder=$itemSort"
       . "&affliate.networkId=9"        // fill in your information in next 3 lines
       . "&affliate.trackingId=123456789"
       . "&affliate.customId=456";

  if ($debug) { print "<br />findItemsAdvanced call = <blockquote>$apicall </blockquote>"; }

  // Load the call and capture the document returned by the Finding API
  $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

  // Check to see if the response was loaded, else print an error
if ($resp->ack == "Success") {


    // If the response was loaded, parse it and build links
    foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
      if ($item->galleryURL) {
        $picURL = $item->galleryURL;
      } else {
        $picURL = "http://pics.ebaystatic.com/aw/pics/express/icons/iconPlaceholder_96x96.gif";
      }
      $link  = $item->viewItemURL;
      $title = $item->title;
      $itemsID = $item->itemId;
      $price = sprintf("%01.2f", $item->sellingStatus->convertedCurrentPrice);
      $ship  = sprintf("%01.2f", $item->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost);
      $total = sprintf("%01.2f", ((float)$item->sellingStatus->convertedCurrentPrice
                    + (float)$item->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost));

        // Determine currency to display - so far only seen cases where priceCurr = shipCurr, but may be others
        $priceCurr = (string) $item->sellingStatus->convertedCurrentPrice['currencyId'];
        $shipCurr  = (string) $item->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost['currencyId'];
        if ($priceCurr == $shipCurr) {
          $curr = $priceCurr;
        } else {
          $curr = "$priceCurr / $shipCurr";  // potential case where price/ship currencies differ
        }

        $timeLeft = getPrettyTimeFromEbayTime($item->sellingStatus->timeLeft);
        $endTime = strtotime($item->listingInfo->endTime);   // returns Epoch seconds
        $endTime = $item->listingInfo->endTime;

      $results .= " <img src=\"$picURL\"> ";
    }

  }
  // If there was no search response, print an error
  else {
    $results = "<h3>No items found matching the $itemType type.";
  }  // if resp

  return $results;

}  // function


?>



<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>GetUserProfile</title>
<script src="./js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jQueryUI/ui.tablesorter.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter({
      sortList:[[7,0],[4,0]],    // upon screen load, sort by col 7, 4 ascending (0)
      debug: false,        // if true, useful to debug Tablesorter issues
      headers: {
        0: { sorter: false },  // col 0 = first = left most column - no sorting
        5: { sorter: false },
        6: { sorter: false },
        7: { sorter: 'text'}   // specify text sorter, otherwise mistakenly takes shortDate parser
      }
    });
  });
</script>

</head>

<body>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/flora.all.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Flora (Default)">

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<table cellpadding="2" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>SellerID</th>
    <th>Site</th>
    <th>ItemType</th>
    <th>ItemSort</th>
    <th>Debug</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="SellerID" value=""></td>
    <td>
      <select name="GlobalID">
        <option value="EBAY-AU">Australia - EBAY-AU (15) - AUD</option>
        <option value="EBAY-ENCA">Canada (English) - EBAY-ENCA (2) - CAD</option>
        <option value="EBAY-DE">Germany - EBAY-DE (77) - EUR</option>
        <option value="EBAY-GB">United Kingdom - EBAY-GB (3) - GBP</option>
        <option selected value="EBAY-US">United States - EBAY-US (0) - USD</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="ItemType">
        <option selected value="All">All Item Types</option>
        <option value="Auction">Auction Items Only</option>
        <option value="FixedPriced">Fixed Priced Item Only</option>
        <option value="StoreInventory">Store Inventory Only</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="ItemSort">
        <option value="BidCountFewest">Bid Count (fewest bids first) [Applies to Auction Items Only]</option>
        <option selected value="EndTimeSoonest">End Time (soonest first)</option>
        <option value="PricePlusShippingLowest">Price + Shipping (lowest first)</option>
        <option value="CurrentPriceHighest">Current Price Highest</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <select name="Debug">
      <option value="1">true</option>
      <option selected value="0">false</option>
      </select>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center"><INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
  print $pageResults;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I also modified it for you so it shows the following for each product found:

1. ID
2. Image
3. Title (linked to the products ebay page)
4. Price (includes currency)
5. Shipping (includes currency)
6. Total (includes currency)
7. Time Left (e.g. 2 hours 6 minutes 46 seconds)
8. Ends (e.g. 2014-03-24T15:22:00.000Z)

Remember to fill in $appID on line 19 with your AppID. You need a developer account on https://developer.ebay.com/ to get it (sandbox keys do NOT work only the production keys work).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<?php

require_once('DisplayUtils.php');  // functions to aid with display of information

//error_reporting(E_ALL);  // turn on all errors, warnings and notices for easier debugging
$sellerID='SellerIdHere';
$pageResults='';
if(isset($_POST['SellerID']))
{
  $s_endpoint = 'http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping';  // Shopping
  $f_endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';  // Finding
  $responseEncoding = 'XML';   // Format of the response
  $s_version = '667';   // Shopping API version number
  $f_version = '1.4.0';   // Finding API version number
  $appID   = 'ENTER_APP_ID_HERE'; //replace this with your AppID

  $debug   = true;
  $debug = (boolean) $_POST['Debug'];

  $sellerID  = urlencode (utf8_encode($_POST['SellerID']));   // cleanse input
  $globalID    = urlencode (utf8_encode($_POST['GlobalID']));

  $sitearray = array(
    'EBAY-US' => '0',
    'EBAY-ENCA' => '2',
    'EBAY-GB' => '3',
    'EBAY-AU' => '15',
    'EBAY-DE' => '77',
  );


  $siteID = $sitearray[$globalID];

  $pageResults = '';
  $pageResults .= getUserProfileResultsAsHTML($sellerID);
  $pageResults .= getFindItemsAdvancedResultsAsHTML($sellerID);

} // if


function getUserProfileResultsAsHTML($sellerID) {
  global $siteID, $s_endpoint, $responseEncoding, $s_version, $appID, $debug;
  $results = '';

  $apicall = "$s_endpoint?callname=GetUserProfile"
       . "&version=$s_version"
       . "&siteid=$siteID"
       . "&appid=$appID"
       . "&UserID=lordbrowns"

       . "&IncludeSelector=Details,FeedbackHistory"   // need Details to get MyWorld info
       . "&responseencoding=$responseEncoding";

  if ($debug) { print "<br />GetUserProfile call = <blockquote>$apicall </blockquote>"; }

  // Load the call and capture the document returned by the Shopping API
  $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

  if ($resp) {
    if (!empty($resp->User->MyWorldLargeImage)) {
      $myWorldImgURL = $resp->User->MyWorldLargeImage;
    } else {
      $myWorldImgURL = 'http://pics.ebaystatic.com/aw/pics/community/myWorld/imgBuddyBig1.gif';
    }
    $results .= "<table><tr>";
    $results .= "<td><a href=\"" . $resp->User->MyWorldURL . "\"><img src=\""
          . $myWorldImgURL . "\"></a></td>";
    $results .= "<td>Seller $sellerID<br /> ";
    $results .= "Feedback score : " . $resp->User->FeedbackScore . "<br />";
    $posCount = $resp->FeedbackHistory->UniquePositiveFeedbackCount;
    $negCount = $resp->FeedbackHistory->UniqueNegativeFeedbackCount;
    $posNegCount = $posCount + $negCount;
    if (!$posNegCount) {
        $posNegCount = 1;
    }
    $posFeedBackPct = sprintf("%01.1f", (100 * ($posCount / $posNegCount)));
    $results .= "Positive feedback : $posFeedBackPct%<br />";
    $regDate = substr($resp->User->RegistrationDate, 0, 10);
    $results .= "Registration date : $regDate<br />";

    $results .= "</tr></table>";

  } else {
    $results = "<h3>No user profile for seller $sellerID";
  }
  return $results;
} // function



function getFindItemsAdvancedResultsAsHTML($sellerID) {
  global $globalID, $f_endpoint, $responseEncoding, $f_version, $appID, $debug;

  $maxEntries = 3;

  $itemType  = urlencode (utf8_encode($_POST['ItemType']));
  $itemSort  = urlencode (utf8_encode($_POST['ItemSort']));

  $results = '<table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="5px" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Shipping</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Time Left</th>
    <th>Ends</th>
  </tr>';
  // Construct the FindItems call
  $apicall = "$f_endpoint?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced"
       . "&version=$f_version"
       . "&GLOBAL-ID=$globalID"
       . "&SECURITY-APPNAME=$appID"   // replace this with your AppID
       . "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=$responseEncoding"
       . "&itemFilter(0).name=Seller"
       . "&itemFilter(0).value=$sellerID"
       . "&itemFilter(1).name=ListingType"
       . "&itemFilter(1).value=$itemType"
       . "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=$maxEntries"
       . "&sortOrder=$itemSort"
       . "&affliate.networkId=9"        // fill in your information in next 3 lines
       . "&affliate.trackingId=123456789"
       . "&affliate.customId=456";

  if ($debug) { print "<br />findItemsAdvanced call = <blockquote>$apicall </blockquote>"; }

  // Load the call and capture the document returned by the Finding API
  $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

  // Check to see if the response was loaded, else print an error
if ($resp->ack == "Success") {


    // If the response was loaded, parse it and build links
    foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
      if ($item->galleryURL) {
        $picURL = $item->galleryURL;
      } else {
        $picURL = "http://pics.ebaystatic.com/aw/pics/express/icons/iconPlaceholder_96x96.gif";
      }
      $link  = $item->viewItemURL;
      $title = $item->title;
      $itemsID = $item->itemId;
      $price = sprintf("%01.2f", $item->sellingStatus->convertedCurrentPrice);
      $ship  = sprintf("%01.2f", $item->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost);
      $total = sprintf("%01.2f", ((float)$item->sellingStatus->convertedCurrentPrice
                    + (float)$item->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost));

        // Determine currency to display - so far only seen cases where priceCurr = shipCurr, but may be others
        $priceCurr = (string) $item->sellingStatus->convertedCurrentPrice['currencyId'];
        $shipCurr  = (string) $item->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost['currencyId'];
        if ($priceCurr == $shipCurr) {
          $curr = $priceCurr;
        } else {
          $curr = "$priceCurr / $shipCurr";  // potential case where price/ship currencies differ
        }

        $timeLeft = getPrettyTimeFromEbayTime($item->sellingStatus->timeLeft);
        $endTime = strtotime($item->listingInfo->endTime);   // returns Epoch seconds
        $endTime = $item->listingInfo->endTime;

        $results .= "<tr>
            <td>$itemsID</td>
            <td><img src=\"$picURL\"></td>
            <td><a href=\"$link\">$title</a></td>
            <td>$price $curr</td>
            <td>$ship $curr</td>
            <td>$total $curr</td>
            <td>$timeLeft</td>
            <td>$endTime</td>
        </tr>";
    }

    $results .= '</table>';

  }
  // If there was no search response, print an error
  else {
    $results = "<h3>No items found matching the $itemType type.";
  }  // if resp

  return $results;

}  // function


?>



<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>GetUserProfile</title>
<script src="./js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jQueryUI/ui.tablesorter.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter({
      sortList:[[7,0],[4,0]],    // upon screen load, sort by col 7, 4 ascending (0)
      debug: false,        // if true, useful to debug Tablesorter issues
      headers: {
        0: { sorter: false },  // col 0 = first = left most column - no sorting
        5: { sorter: false },
        6: { sorter: false },
        7: { sorter: 'text'}   // specify text sorter, otherwise mistakenly takes shortDate parser
      }
    });
  });
</script>

</head>

<body>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/flora.all.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Flora (Default)">

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<table cellpadding="2" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>SellerID</th>
    <th>Site</th>
    <th>ItemType</th>
    <th>ItemSort</th>
    <th>Debug</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="SellerID" value=""></td>
    <td>
      <select name="GlobalID">
        <option value="EBAY-AU">Australia - EBAY-AU (15) - AUD</option>
        <option value="EBAY-ENCA">Canada (English) - EBAY-ENCA (2) - CAD</option>
        <option value="EBAY-DE">Germany - EBAY-DE (77) - EUR</option>
        <option value="EBAY-GB">United Kingdom - EBAY-GB (3) - GBP</option>
        <option selected value="EBAY-US">United States - EBAY-US (0) - USD</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="ItemType">
        <option selected value="All">All Item Types</option>
        <option value="Auction">Auction Items Only</option>
        <option value="FixedPriced">Fixed Priced Item Only</option>
        <option value="StoreInventory">Store Inventory Only</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="ItemSort">
        <option value="BidCountFewest">Bid Count (fewest bids first) [Applies to Auction Items Only]</option>
        <option selected value="EndTimeSoonest">End Time (soonest first)</option>
        <option value="PricePlusShippingLowest">Price + Shipping (lowest first)</option>
        <option value="CurrentPriceHighest">Current Price Highest</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <select name="Debug">
      <option value="1">true</option>
      <option selected value="0">false</option>
      </select>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center"><INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
  print $pageResults;
```

Here is an example of a products API response from Ebay, in case it helps. It shows all the possible properties you can get about each product.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<findItemsAdvancedResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
    <ack>Success</ack>
    <version>1.12.0</version>
    <timestamp>2014-03-24T13:04:11.650Z</timestamp>
    <searchResult count="3">
        <item>
            <itemId>111304063912</itemId>
            <title>Outdoor Wicker 10 Seater Teak Timber Dining Table And Chairs Furniture Setting</title>
            <globalId>EBAY-AU</globalId>
            <primaryCategory>
                <categoryId>139849</categoryId>
                <categoryName>Sets</categoryName>
            </primaryCategory>
            <galleryURL>http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/mUPmUHtcIb4BJcnGF7Qol_A/140.jpg</galleryURL>
            <viewItemURL>http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Outdoor-Wicker-10-Seater-Teak-Timber-Dining-Table-And-Chairs-Furniture-Setting-/111304063912?pt=AU_OutdoorFurniture</viewItemURL>
            <paymentMethod>CIPInCheckoutEnabled</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>MOCC</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>PersonalCheck</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>VisaMC</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>PaymentSeeDescription</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>MoneyXferAccepted</paymentMethod>
            <autoPay>false</autoPay>
            <postalCode>2750</postalCode>
            <location>South Penrith,NSW,Australia</location>
            <country>AU</country>
            <shippingInfo>
                <shippingType>Freight</shippingType>
                <shipToLocations>AU</shipToLocations>
            </shippingInfo>
            <sellingStatus>
                <currentPrice currencyId="AUD">1999.0</currentPrice>
                <convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="AUD">1999.0</convertedCurrentPrice>
                <sellingState>Active</sellingState>
                <timeLeft>P0DT2H17M49S</timeLeft>
            </sellingStatus>
            <listingInfo>
                <bestOfferEnabled>true</bestOfferEnabled>
                <buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
                <startTime>2014-03-19T15:22:00.000Z</startTime>
                <endTime>2014-03-24T15:22:00.000Z</endTime>
                <listingType>StoreInventory</listingType>
                <gift>false</gift>
            </listingInfo>
            <galleryPlusPictureURL>http://galleryplus.ebayimg.com/ws/web/111304063912_1_0_1.jpg</galleryPlusPictureURL>
            <condition>
                <conditionId>1000</conditionId>
                <conditionDisplayName>Brand New</conditionDisplayName>
            </condition>
            <isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
            <topRatedListing>true</topRatedListing>
        </item>
        <item>
            <itemId>111306128036</itemId>
            <title>Outdoor Wicker Modular Lounge Suite Cane Rattan Furniture Setting Sofa DayBed</title>
            <globalId>EBAY-AU</globalId>
            <primaryCategory>
                <categoryId>139849</categoryId>
                <categoryName>Sets</categoryName>
            </primaryCategory>
            <galleryURL>http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/pict/1113061280364040_1.jpg</galleryURL>
            <viewItemURL>http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Outdoor-Wicker-Modular-Lounge-Suite-Cane-Rattan-Furniture-Setting-Sofa-DayBed-/111306128036?pt=AU_OutdoorFurniture</viewItemURL>
            <paymentMethod>CIPInCheckoutEnabled</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>MOCC</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>PersonalCheck</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>VisaMC</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>PaymentSeeDescription</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>MoneyXferAccepted</paymentMethod>
            <autoPay>false</autoPay>
            <postalCode>2749</postalCode>
            <location>Cranebrook,NSW,Australia</location>
            <country>AU</country>
            <shippingInfo>
                <shippingType>Freight</shippingType>
                <shipToLocations>AU</shipToLocations>
            </shippingInfo>
            <sellingStatus>
                <currentPrice currencyId="AUD">1399.0</currentPrice>
                <convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="AUD">1399.0</convertedCurrentPrice>
                <bidCount>0</bidCount>
                <sellingState>Active</sellingState>
                <timeLeft>P0DT4H54M20S</timeLeft>
            </sellingStatus>
            <listingInfo>
                <bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
                <buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
                <startTime>2014-03-21T17:58:31.000Z</startTime>
                <endTime>2014-03-24T17:58:31.000Z</endTime>
                <listingType>Auction</listingType>
                <gift>false</gift>
            </listingInfo>
            <galleryPlusPictureURL>http://galleryplus.ebayimg.com/ws/web/111306128036_1_0_1.jpg</galleryPlusPictureURL>
            <condition>
                <conditionId>1000</conditionId>
                <conditionDisplayName>Brand New</conditionDisplayName>
            </condition>
            <isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
            <topRatedListing>true</topRatedListing>
        </item>
        <item>
            <itemId>111306305056</itemId>
            <title>Outdoor Wicker 8 Seater Rectangle Dining Table and Chairs Furniture Setting Set</title>
            <globalId>EBAY-AU</globalId>
            <primaryCategory>
                <categoryId>139849</categoryId>
                <categoryName>Sets</categoryName>
            </primaryCategory>
            <galleryURL>http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/mMoVkPcCBnFqTnrVExI2EYg/140.jpg</galleryURL>
            <viewItemURL>http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Outdoor-Wicker-8-Seater-Rectangle-Dining-Table-and-Chairs-Furniture-Setting-Set-/111306305056?pt=AU_OutdoorFurniture</viewItemURL>
            <paymentMethod>CIPInCheckoutEnabled</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>MOCC</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>PersonalCheck</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>VisaMC</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>PaymentSeeDescription</paymentMethod>
            <paymentMethod>MoneyXferAccepted</paymentMethod>
            <autoPay>false</autoPay>
            <postalCode>2750</postalCode>
            <location>South Penrith,NSW,Australia</location>
            <country>AU</country>
            <shippingInfo>
                <shippingType>Freight</shippingType>
                <shipToLocations>AU</shipToLocations>
            </shippingInfo>
            <sellingStatus>
                <currentPrice currencyId="AUD">1689.0</currentPrice>
                <convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="AUD">1689.0</convertedCurrentPrice>
                <bidCount>0</bidCount>
                <sellingState>Active</sellingState>
                <timeLeft>P0DT8H47M11S</timeLeft>
            </sellingStatus>
            <listingInfo>
                <bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
                <buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
                <startTime>2014-03-21T21:51:22.000Z</startTime>
                <endTime>2014-03-24T21:51:22.000Z</endTime>
                <listingType>Auction</listingType>
                <gift>false</gift>
            </listingInfo>
            <galleryPlusPictureURL>http://galleryplus.ebayimg.com/ws/web/111306305056_1_0_1.jpg</galleryPlusPictureURL>
            <condition>
                <conditionId>1000</conditionId>
                <conditionDisplayName>Brand New</conditionDisplayName>
            </condition>
            <isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
            <topRatedListing>true</topRatedListing>
        </item>
    </searchResult>
    <paginationOutput>
        <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
        <entriesPerPage>3</entriesPerPage>
        <totalPages>39</totalPages>
        <totalEntries>116</totalEntries>
    </paginationOutput>
    <itemSearchURL>http://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_sasl=united_house&amp;_saslop=1&amp;_fss=1&amp;LH_IncludeSIF=1&amp;LH_SpecificSeller=1&amp;_ddo=1&amp;_ipg=3&amp;_pgn=1&amp;_sop=1</itemSearchURL>
</findItemsAdvancedResponse>
```

More information can be found in this tutorial (for other users who want the tutorial the posters code is based off):
http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/HowTo/PHP_Shopping/PHP_FIA_GUP_Interm_NV_XML/PHP_FIA_GUP_Interm_NV_XML.html

Comment: Can someone help me find the ShippingProfileID, ReturnProfileID and the PaymantProfilID ? –